# Bigquery - View old scheduled query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Good morning. I updated my scheduled query but I would like to view the previous version. Is there a way to access a previous version of a scheduled query? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the old one ever ran in the past, you may query the information_schema to get the query running in the past. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs

Comment: If you have ever ran the old query it should appear on Query history on Bigquery console.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these 4 steps:

1. Go to menu bar and select ***Scheduled queries***.

   [image]
2. Select the query you want to check out.

   [image]
3. Click on the ***Configuration*** option here.

   [image]
4. Scroll down and check here the ***Query String***.

   [image]

   Tip: To understand the query, paste it in the BigQuery editor and format it.

   [image]

Comment: This answer explains how to visualize the current version - the question is about how to find a previous version